# Error: Resolver associated with data sources

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, serverless, aws-appsync

I'm having the serverless error:
`Resolver associated with data sources` when building from serverless.yml config file:

```
# serverless.yml
...
mappingTemplates:
  - dataSource: Wallet
    type: Query
    field: walletFromId
    request: "_dynamo-get-wallet.txt"
    response: "_generic-result-response.txt"
  - dataSource: Wallet
    type: Query
    field: walletsFromUser
    request: "_dynamo-get-wallets-from-user.txt"
    response: "_generic-result-response.txt"
  - dataSource: Wallet
    type: Mutation
    field: registerWallet
    request: "_dynamo-put-wallet.txt"
    response: "_generic-result-response.txt"
dataSources:
  - type: AMAZON_DYNAMODB
    name: Wallet
    description: 'Wallet DataSource'
    config:
      tableName: "${self:custom.stage}-Wallet"
      serviceRoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::${self:custom.accountId}:role/${self:custom.appSync.serviceRole}"
...
```

I also have a schema.graphql:

```
type Query {
    # query the wallet with given id and get the output with detail info
    walletFromId(walletId: String!): Wallet!
    # query wallets with given user id and get list of cards
    walletsFromUser(userId: String!): [Wallet!]!
}

type Mutation {
    # Add a wallet to an existing user
    registerWallet(userId: String!, number: String!, cvx: String!, expirationDate: String!): Wallet!
}
type Wallet {
    walletId: String!
    userId: String!
    number: String!
    cvx: String!
    expirationDate: String!
}

type Subscription {
    addWallet: Wallet
    @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["registerWallet"])
}

schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
    subscription: Subscription
}
```

I could not find a single clue as to what this error mean, and there isn't anything else I can get from the build logs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error usually means you are trying to delete a data source that is currently being used by a resolver. If you can identify the resolver pointing to the data source and delete it then you should no longer see the error message.

Comment: Yeah it's on the aws console.

Comment: They are in the right half of the page where you see the "Attach" button in the schema tab.

Comment: Any way to delete many of them at once ?? I have way to many and want a clean start

Comment: I believe removing the fields from the schema should do the trick

Comment: the same when using Terraform

Comment: @mparis is right. I can't delete Data Sources unless removing fields from the schema first.